# Как изменить направление движения предмета без его торможения?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Предмет движется с помощью физики rigidbody.

Как резко изменить направление движения предмета без его торможения?

```
_agent = GetComponentInChildren<NavMeshAgent>();

_agent.speed = 100;

//так меняется направление движения:
_agent.SetDestination(_target.position)
```

Comment: а что в `SetDestination` ? а как он у вас движется с помощью физики rigidbody? можно подробнее?

Comment: А пробовали напрямую velocity знак поменять?

Answer (score 1):

Если мы взглянем на систему координат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то видим, что при движении по оси X вправо (обозначим как **вперед**) - значения увеличиваются, при движении влево (**назад**) - уменьшаются. Для оси Y аналогично, но вверх/вниз.

Допустим, у нас игрок движется с постоянной скоростью 50. Не важно чего 50 - ёжиков в секунду или свеклы в борще. То есть каждый определенный промежуток времени он проходит расстояние 50: 50-100-150-200... Из логики системы координат видим, что движется вперед - значит значения увеличиваются. Для движения назад - надо чтоб уменьшались. Можно иметь два значения скорости: для движения вперед **+50**, для значения назад **-50**, но это не очень эффективно. Не иметь же по два значения на каждый параметр. Нужно просто сделать скорость с другим знаком, но тем же значением (50). Как? Конечно умножить на -1.

если утрированно, персонаж двигался в положительную сторону

```
rigidbody.AddForce(transform.right * speed);
```

персонаж движется в обратную сторону

```
rigidbody.AddForce(transform.right * (speed * -1));
```

В Юнити бывают для этих целей (если персонаж управляется с клавиатуры допустим) используют [Input.GetAxis](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html), который уже возвращает значение от -1 до 1, в зависимости от того, куда давит юзер.

```
-1 назад, 1 - вперед, 0 - ничего не давит
```

пример:

```
var fwd: float = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * (driveForce * fwd));
var steer: float = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * (steer * fwd));
```